# How to fix "storage.ide-shm is being used by another process", which prevents me from committing

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, commit

In my visual studio solution with TFS, I try to commit the changes I made but I get the error message below all the time.

I don't have enough reputation to put an image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpumG.png)

Translation of the message : The process cannot access the file'C:\Users\SESA474351\Source\Workspaces\Kiosk\eKiosk - DEVELOPMENT. vs\Kiosk Solution\v15\Server\sqlite3\storage.ide-shm', because it is being used by another process

I tried to delete all my projects locally and recover them. I tried to run visual studio as an administrator. I tried to cancel all the pending changes.
Nothing worked

When I click on archive, my code is supposed to be committed in TFS but it doesn't work, do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure that you're not checking in files and folders that you don't need (i.e. bin, obj, and .vs folders). To exclude such things, you should use a .tfignore file if you're using TFVC or a .gitignore file if you're using git.

To try and solve your immediate problem, close down you Visual Studio and then delete the .vs folder. If that also complains about being used by another process, try to reboot first and then delete the folder and load the solution again and then see if you can commit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I tried what you said, and the first step to follow is to delete the.vs folder from the TFS. Then everything works again... 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue where I couldn't check-in at all, with Visual Studio Pro 2019 (16.0).  Turns out I had unintentionally included the storage.ide-shm under the hidden .vs folder into a check-in.  This folder should not be included under source control.

To fix you need to delete the .vs folder via the Source Control Explorer.  As an added bonus, so you don't accidentally do it again, add that folder to the .tfignore file.  The quickest way to do this is if you see anything to do with the .vs folder under the Team Explorer => Pending Changes => Excluded Changes => Detected link, and right click the offending file and ignore the folder.  You can then edit the .tfignore file and trim the entry down to just .vs.  This will now ignore anything under the .vs folder.